# How to change context of a Project Cumulative Flow chart in Rally?

Tags: javascript, rally

I am using the [Project Cumulative Flow chart](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/cfd-chart) to show Rally defects over time. In this example, the project is chosen by the default context of the app:

```
_ProjectHierarchy: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID
```

Where 'this' is the instance of the App.

What I'd like to do is change the context but nothing I've tried was successful.
I have tried changing the context property of the storeConfig from:

```
context: this.getContext().getDataContext()
```

to:

```
context: {
    project: '/project/123456'
}
```

with my real project object ID but this doesn't make a difference. Please help me change the context of my App instance or change the context of SnapshotStore so that I can search within my desired project.

Answer (score 1):

The Lookback API and the SnapshotStore behave a bit differently than the standard Web Services API and Store. You'll want to leave the context on your storeConfig as you had it, mostly so it gets the correct workspace.

_ProjectHierarchy is the correct place to do this.  If you just edit the settings on your app and scope it to the desired project the code above will already work.  Otherwise, you can just hardcode in the ObjectID of the desired project.

[image]

[image]

Also, may I suggest starting with the most recently released version of the SDK: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/

Comment: "edit the settings on your app and scope it to the desired project" - could you explain how to do this please? I have tried putting a context key inside the object that I Ext.define as CustomApp but this didn't seem to work. The documentation on context and scoping doesn't describe how to set a new context, only read from the current context. Thanks!

Comment: i added screenshots above demonstrating how to edit the scoping via the app settings...

Comment: What about if I'm developing the app externally of Rally? I just want to run my app in the browser using the rally-app-builder web server. How is the default context decided and how can I change it?

Comment: By default it will use the default project set in your User Profile.  You can specify a specific project by using the project=/project/12345 query string parameter as mentioned here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/developing_externally-section-controlling-context

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was after. I should have noticed this page in the documentation myself, sorry about that. Thanks Kyle!